# How I can fill column of the table with a different values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have:

```
                        ID   |      Text
                     =====================
                             |      'a'                 
                             |      'b'                 
                             |      'c'
```

I need:

```
                       ID  |      Text
                     =====================
                       3   |      'a'            
                       5   |      'b'                                
                       9   |      'c'
```

The numbers in `ID` can be any, it's just an example.

I know about `INSERT INTO`, but it requires to write all data for each string. Also, I know about `UPDATE`, but it fills a column with the same values. I am studying SQL only few days, so most likely I missed something.

Comment: You'll have to show how the `id` values relate to the `text` values or no one will be able to provide an answer

Comment: Can't I just fill column with random numbers, that i think up? Goes there have to be any sequence? What if there would be another text column instead ID?

Comment: Random numbers is fine but should all rows with a certain `Text` value (such as 'a') have the same `ID` value?

Comment: All `Text` values in my table are different, but if there were the same values, yes they should have the same `ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ID` values can be any random number then the easiest solution to identify all unique `Text` values and assign an id value to them would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Text) (random() * 1000000000)::integer AS r, Text 
FROM your_table
```

This does run the (small) risk that an identical id value will be generated for distinct rows which would be problematic if the `ID` has associated constraints on them for referential integrity (e.g. you use the `ID` value to link to other tables). A more sturdy solution using window functions that avoids this issue is:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Text) AS r, Text
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (Text) Text FROM your_table) x;
```

The inner query (with alias `x`) identifies all unique `Text` values, the outer query then assigns an id value that starts at 1 and increments over the identifies rows, alphabetically ordered.

Updating the original table is now straightforward:

```
UPDATE your_table SET ID = subq.r
FROM ( <<pick one of the SELECT clauses above>> ) subq
WHERE your_table.Text = subq.Text;
```

Should your table have more columns than `Text` that you want to use to identify unique rows, then you can add those columns in the `DISTINCT ON` and column lists of the inner query, as well as the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement.